# Prev and next buttons on horizontal content

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I'm building a large comparison table, it's width will be wider than the screen most of the time. I need to add some simple previous and next arrow buttons so uses can 'scroll' horizontally through the wide table. Something like on this website: https://www.commbank.com.au/personal/credit-cards/compare.html

Is there any jquery plugins or anything for this? Just for the previous and next buttons. I've got all the jquery I need to make the table responsive etc. Thanks.

Comment: its called a slider man, a SLIDER there are billions on the www

Comment: Wow thanks I didn't realise that! The main issue is getting the previous and next button to work on a table. I can't group the columns in to slides like you normally would so I'm not sure how it works on a comparison type table.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the end which works well: http://naminho.ch/scroll-indicator